# Inverse operation of xor

Tags: propositional-calculus, binary, binary-operations, bit-strings

If $x = a$ xor $b$, given the values of $x$ and $a$ can we find $b$? In other words, which function can be applied on both sides in the equation to get the value of $b$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XOR is its own inverse and it's commutative, so $x = a \oplus b \implies x\oplus a = a \oplus b \oplus a = 0 \oplus b = b$

Answer (score 1):

For any $b$ and $a$, it is true that $b = (\underbrace{a \operatorname{XOR} b}_{\textrm{your }x}) \operatorname{XOR}a$.